# VB.NET How to Export/insert whole DataGridView Data to Sqlite Table in one go

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am succefful importing an excel file into dataset and datatable.
My dgv contains more than 50 columns and 2000 rows and columns are equal and matching with sqlite table.

Please help how can i export all dgv data to SQLite Table and overwriting the old data if any present in Sqlite table.

I found this code block but cannot understand as I am only familier witg vb.net and hence cannot work with this code.

```
    string StrQuery;
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            for(int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" 
                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Text+", " 
                    + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Text+");";
                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is merely looping through all the rows in the datagridview and doing an insert for each one.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some research on how ADO.NET works. There's lots of information out there for beginners on that subject. Instead of trying to learn just enough for this one function, learn the basics of the topic as a whole and then apply that knowledge to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Below code is main command:**

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim stid As String = ""
            MessageBox.Show("This process will take 30-60 seconds so please wait and do not cancel/abort the operation.", "World Systems", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim StrQuery As String = "INSERT INTO tblmaindata VALUES('" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(17).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(18).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(19).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(20).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(21).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(22).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(23).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(24).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(25).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(26).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(27).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(28).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(29).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(30).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(31).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(32).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(33).Value.ToString.Replace("'", "") & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(34).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(35).Value & "','" & stid & "')"
                RunSQL2(StrQuery)
            Next
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        MessageBox.Show("Total: " & c & " Records successfully imported and inserted into database.", "World Systems", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End Sub
```

```
 Public Sub RunSQL2(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            condb()
            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            c = c + 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Operation Failed, Nothing Saved!", "Information : World Systems", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

This code perfectly works.